# Путь в файле .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, файлы, php

Уважаемые господа!
Форум стоял на домене /.
Я хочу его засунуть в папку /forum/
Как правильно это сделать?

По моему мнению нужно прописать путь в файле .htaccess:

```
#   Mod_security can interfere with uploading of content such as attachments. If you
#   cannot attach files, remove the "#" from the lines below.
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#   SecFilterEngine Off
#   SecFilterScanPOST Off
#</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 401 default
ErrorDocument 403 default
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 500 default

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #   If you are having problems with the rewrite rules, remove the "#" from the
    #   line that begins "RewriteBase" below. You will also have to change the path
    #   of the rewrite to reflect the path to your XenForo installation.
    #RewriteBase /xenforo

    #   This line may be needed to enable WebDAV editing with PHP as a CGI.
    #RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(data/|js/|styles/|install/|favicon\.ico) - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: с чего вдруг только .htaccess? в настройках или в БД пути не используются? прочитайте комментарий про rewritebase в этом файле.

Comment: Так что надо сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Прочитать вот этот кусок:

```
#   If you are having problems with the rewrite rules, remove the "#" from the
#   line that begins "RewriteBase" below. You will also have to change the path
#   of the rewrite to reflect the path to your XenForo installation.
#RewriteBase /xenforo
```

Comment: Так вроде первым делом это сделал:

 
 RewriteBase /forum/xenforo

 # This line may be needed to enable WebDAV editing with PHP as a CGI.
 #RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^(data/|js/|styles/|install/|favicon\.ico) - [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^.*$ /forum/index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: так где форум-то стоял? в корне, если я правильно понял? а сейчас переехал в `/forum/`? почему тогда вы тут `RewriteBase /forum/xenforo`? Хоть немного логики включите... вот это что такое? `RewriteRule ^.*$ /forum/index.php [NC,L]`

[погуглили](http://www.xf-russia.ru/xenforo/faq.html#how-migrate) бы сначала

Comment: Помогите, как правильно?
Я уже и так пробовал и так...